# Iterate Json object using Scala2

Tags: json, scala, iteration, ujson, upickle

Newbie Scala user's here! I was trying to extract all elements in a JSON array one by one, so I was iterating this object. Since Scala doesn't have built-in JSON support, I used a third-party JSON parsing package [ujson](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/upickle/#GettingStarted). I am trying to implement a for-loop on a JSON array like this:

```
var json = ujson.read("""{"list": ["id":1, "id":2, "id":3]}""")
var index = 0
var iteration: Boolean = true
while(iteration) {
  try {
    print(json("list")(index))
    index += 1
  }
  catch {
    iteration = false
  }
}
```

It encountered a compilation error on the line `iteration = false` and said `type mismatch;`. So in this question, I am looking for the things listed below:

1. **Are there any 3rd-party packages able to handle the iteration on JSON arrays?** I've only tried 3 of them I knew so I can't guarantee we can't iterate without a dummy function like mine.
2. If I keep using *upickle*, is it the way we do iteration?
3. What does the error stand for in my code?

Scala version: 2.13.12

Comment: The compilation error is because that is not [how you write a try catch block](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/control-structures.html#try%20catch%20finally). Before iteration you need to add `case ex =>`. Besides that, I first recommend to follow a tutorial to learn scala basic concepts.

Comment: `["id":1, "id":2, "id":3]` isn't even valid JSON. Once you fix that, iterating and printing should be something like `ujson.read("""<valid json>""")("list").arr.foreach(println)`, definitely without all this `boolean`-`var`-`while`-`try`-`catch` stone age stuff.

Comment: Thank you both! You rock! I really am not familiar with Scala syntax yet.